# Partition of circumference into $3k$ arcs

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, generating-functions

The following problem is from 1982 Russian Mathematical Olympiad. If you go to this [link](http://cage.ugent.be/~hvernaev/olympiad.html), and scroll down to the section Russian Math Olympiad, then this is Problem 333 in that text-file.

> Let $k$ be a positive integer. There are $3k$ points marked on the circumference. They divide the circumference onto $3k$ arcs. Some $k$ of arcs have length 1, other $k$ of them have length 2, the rest $k$ of them have length 3. Prove that some two of the marked points are the ends of one diameter.

I haven't given too much thought into the problem yet (I probably wouldn't get anywhere), but I thought I would share this awesome problem.

**Added.** Trivial Observation: The length of the circumference is $k+2k+3k=6k$.

Comment: Is this one doable with generating function?

Comment: @Aqua: I have no idea. If you can come up with such an argument, you should post it! I'd love to see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume the crontrary and assume $k$ is chosen minimal. 
One directly checks that then $k\ge 2$ (i.e. the claim holds for $k=1$ where the arrangement is completely determined up to symmetry).

Colour the given $3k$ points green and their antipodes red.
Then one readily sees that the red and green points together partition the circumference into $6k$ arcs all of length $1$ (all points are at integer positions on the circumference of length $6k$).
Then any two adjacent green points $ \color{green}\bullet \color{green}\bullet $ (i.e. those making one of the $k$ marked arcs of length $1$) are opposite to two adjacent red points, which must be the interior of a length $3$ arc $\color{green}\bullet \color{red}\bullet \color{red}\bullet \color{green}\bullet $. Hence the neighbourhood of the length $1$ look like $\color{red}\bullet \color{green}\bullet \color{green}\bullet \color{red}\bullet $ (especially, length $1$ arcs cannot be juxtaposed).
Assume the (right) neighbbour of a length $1$ arc is a length $2$ arc, 
$ \color{red}\bullet \color{green}\bullet \color{green}\bullet \color{red}\bullet \color{green}\bullet $.
Then opposite this we find $ \color{green}\bullet \color{red}\bullet \color{red}\bullet \color{green}\bullet \color{red}\bullet $ and these two patterns do not overlap (because $k\ge2$ and there are at least $12$ coloured points).
By removing the inner three dots of each of these two patterns, 
$$\begin{align}\color{red}\bullet \color{green}\bullet \color{green}\bullet \color{red}\bullet \color{green}\bullet&\quad\mapsto\quad\color{red}\bullet \color{green}\bullet\\
\color{green}\bullet \color{red}\bullet \color{red}\bullet \color{green}\bullet \color{red}\bullet&\quad\mapsto\quad\color{green}\bullet \color{red}\bullet\\
\end{align}$$
we obtain a valid pattern again, but with one arc of each length less. 
In other words we find an arrangement for the case $k-1$, which contradicts the minimality of $k$.

Comment: Dear Hagen, this is brilliant! Using colors was especially helpful. Thank you!