# Every number in the set $ M = \{1,2, \ldots ,2008\}$ is one of the three colors blue, yellow, red such that each color...

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation, contest-math, generating-functions

> Consider the set $ M = \{1,2, \ldots
> ,2008\}$. Paint every number in the set $ M$ with one of the three
>   colors blue, yellow, red such that each color is utilized to paint
>   at least one number. Define two sets:
>   $$ S_1=\{(x,y,z)\in M^3 \mid x,y,z\; {\rm have\; the\; same\; color\; and\;
> }2008 | (x + y + z)\}$$ $$ S_2=\{(x,y,z)\in M^3 \mid x,y,z\;{\rm 
> have\; pairwisely\; different\; colors\; and\; }2008 | (x + y + z)\}$$
>   Prove that $ 2|S_1| > |S_2|$ (where $ |X|$ denotes the number of
>   elements in a set $ X$).

**(Online) Solution:** The residue (I mean zero here!) is
just meaningless.In other words,one can prove the same comparation
for $ x+y+z=d(\pmod n)$ (I put $ 2008=n$ for generality) So assume
three generating functions: $$ A(x) = \sum_{a\ is \ red}x^{a -
d/3}$$ $$ B(x) = \sum_{b\ is\ blue}x^{b - d/3}$$ and $$ C(x) =
\sum_{c \ is\ yellow}x^{c - d/3}$$ So all we need to prove is as
follows: $$ 2\times \frac {1}{n}(\sum_{x|x^n = 1}A(x)^3 + B(x)^3 +
C(x)^3) > \frac {6}{n}(\sum_{x|x^n = 1}A(x)\times B(x)\times
C(x))$$ It follows directly from CS inequality (easily
to check that the equality won't occur)!

**Now my question here is: How can they apply CS if there are not even a real numbers?**

Comment: Didn't think it through, but I would guess that $A(x)^3$ calculates the cases with three reds, $B(x)^3$ three blues, and $C(x)^3$ three yellows. In contrast $A(x)B(x)C(x)$ calculates the number of cases with the first component red, second blue, and the last yellow. Because we don't care about the order of the colors in the latter case we multiply by $3!$.

Comment: I would test this hypothesis about the behavior of the generating functions with a toy example. Such as $M=\{1,2,\ldots,7\}$. Need to think about it more to make that meaningful. Sorry about commenting in haste.

Comment: Can you link to the solution directly? I believe we need to find the constant term of the expression, so we need something stronger.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h224619_two_sets @CalvinLin

Comment: I suspect the solution is incomplete. We need to evaluate the constant term of the generating function. It seems like they are doing a sum over the roots of unity (which would give us exactly $n$ times the constant term, hence the 1/n factor in the equation), but I don't think the inequality holds true for all of the roots. Maybe they did something extra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think application of C-S is the right approach, at least not directly.  However, note the following (I changed your variable from $x$ to $t$ since I feel $x$ is used for two different meanings):
$$A(t)+B(t)+C(t)=t^{-d/3}\sum_{k\in M}t^k.$$
If we replace $t$ by $\zeta_l=e^{\frac{2\pi i l}{n}}$, then it follows that
$$A(\zeta_l)+B(\zeta_l)+C(\zeta_l)=0$$
for $l=1,2,\ldots,n-1$ (recalling that $M=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$).  From the identity $$p^3+q^3+r^3-3pqr=(p+q+r)(p^2+q^2+r^2-qr-rp-pq),$$ it follows that $p^3+q^3+r^3=3pqr$ if $p+q+r=0$, and so
$$\big(A(\zeta_l)\big)^3+\big(B(\zeta_l)\big)^3+\big(C(\zeta_l)\big)^3=3\cdot A(\zeta_l)\cdot B(\zeta_l)\cdot C(\zeta_l).$$
On the other hand,
$$\big(A(\zeta_0)\big)^3+\big(B(\zeta_0)\big)^3+\big(C(\zeta_0)\big)^3=\big(A(1)\big)^3+\big(B(1)\big)^3+\big(C(1)\big)^3$$
satisfies $A(1),B(1),C(1)\geq 0$.  Therefore, we can apply AM-GM (or C-S) to get
$$\big(A(\zeta_0)\big)^3+\big(B(\zeta_0)\big)^3+\big(C(\zeta_0)\big)^3\geq 3\cdot A(1)\cdot B(1)\cdot C(1)=3\cdot A(\zeta_0)\cdot B(\zeta_0)\cdot C(\zeta_0).$$
Therefore,
$$\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}\Big(\big(A(\zeta_l)\big)^3+\big(B(\zeta_l)\big)^3+\big(C(\zeta_l)\big)^3\Big)\geq \sum_{l=0}^{n-1}\Big(3\cdot A(\zeta_l)\cdot B(\zeta_l)\cdot C(\zeta_l)\Big),$$
which is equivalent to the required result.

Indeed, it can be shown that
\begin{align}2|S_1|-|S_2|&=2\Big(\big(A(1)\big)^2+\big(B(1)\big)^2+\big(C(1)\big)^2-B(1)\cdot C(1)-C(1)\cdot A(1)-A(1)\cdot B(1)\Big)\\&=\big(B(1)-C(1)\big)^2+\big(C(1)-A(1)\big)^2+\big(A(1)-B(1)\big)^2.\end{align}

Comment: Great! What do you think about this one, is it doable with GF: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513577/choose-3n-points-on-a-circle-show-that-there-are-two-diametrically-opposite-p

Comment: I would be very surprised if this problem has a GF solution, but I will think about it.

Comment: What about this one: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1480694p11608417